# Xampp's APACHE not working?

Tags: apache, xampp

I have installed/reinstalled Xampp server on my laptop for a million times now, and still Apache is not running. At first, it will Run, but few moments later it will automatically stop. I don't know what seems to be the conflict. I have checked my Skype since I once met a conflict on the port usage but in this case, I haven't installed Skype. Can someone please guide me on how to make my Apache run successfully. Note that my mySql runs smoothly, only Apache won't. Please help..:(

P.S.

When I run my xampp-control panel, mySql runs smoothly whereas Apache will run for a moment and then will stop, below in the control panel, it will then say apache[port 80] is busy.

Comment: i hope someone will answer this post, i have met the same dilemma a long time ago and until now I did not solve it, that's why I left Windows.

Answer (score 3):

What caused this problem on my system (Windows 7) was that the WinHTTP Web Proxy Auto-Discovery Service had stopped running. In the Services part of the Computer Management feature (i.e. the app that runs by selecting Manage from the right-click menu on the Computer link on the Start Menu), I found that WinHTTP Discovery Service was set to 'Manual'. I left it as 'Manual', but started it, and Apache began working again.

Even though I didn't change the 'Manual' nature of the service's startup, I discovered that, after Windows reboot, the WinHTTP service was still running (which was a bit puzzling to me, but there we are). I also don't know what caused this service to stop running on my machine ('but there we are' again!)

Anyway, it seems that having WinHTTP Web Proxy Auto-Discovery Service running is necessary for Apache to run, so make sure it's running!

EDIT TO ADD: I found the root cause of my problem: I'd downloaded a free game that uses Pando (peer-to-peer file sharing app) to allow others to download the game from my machine too (which, in principle, I was okay with), and it uses TCP port 443, which was stopping Apache running. I assume (though really don't know enough about networking to be sure) that the running of the WinHTTP Web Proxy Auto-Discovery Service mentioned above was managing to share (or otherwise work around) the use of port 443.

Answer (score 1):

Open a cmd as Administrator (Start -> "cmd" -> right-click "cmd.exe" -> Run as Administrator)

Type

```
netstat -nab
```

Find the line that says

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:80
```

well or basically every line that ends with :80

See the exe that's blocking the port above the line.
Terminate the associated program - if nothing else works the Task-Manager should help.

EDIT: Usually IIS would block Port 80 if it is started. There are quite a lot of other programs that could block port 80 though. You can also try and

```
telnet localhost 80
```

and see what kind of service answers. Or... use a webbrowser. Or... configure apache to use a different port (but who wants to do that?)

Answer (score 1):

Reconfigure Apache to run on a different port

You might want to pick this path if you don’t want to close the application blocking port 80. A typical reason might be that you want to run say, Apache and IIS on the same machine at the same time.

To configure Apache to run on a different port, goto this path "C:\xampp\apache\conf" (if you install Xampp on diffrent place then navigate to this path) and open httpd.conf in notepad. Search for the following lines:

[image: Line 1]
Line 1 :  Listen 80 
[image: Line 2]
Line 2 :  ServerName localhost:80

Change both these lines, so as to have a different number instead of 80. I have chosen 8000 instead of 80. Make sure that this is a free port, not used by any applications.

Line 1 :  Listen 8000 
Line 2 :  ServerName localhost:8000 
Save the file and run Apache from Xampp

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling your Anti-Virus software temporarily. It's known to cause Apache problems. Also check Apache error.log file to see if it has recorded any issues.

Also [try some other WAMPs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_WAMPs) to see if it's a common problem on your system.

Answer (score 0):

Skype automatically blocks the port 80

Stop Skype - Try the apache to start from xampp dashboard

If apache Works - change skype settings

Comment: Clear instructions, but from the question: "I have checked my Skype since I once met a conflict on the port usage but in this case, I haven't installed Skype."

Answer (score 0):

1) In the system tray, we click on the xampp icon.
2) Select Apache> httpd.conf
3) Make a call to Listen 80.
4) Change the number 80 next to Listen to 9080.
5) Restart XAMPP's services