# How to resolve a possible Apache port conflict in XAMPP?

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I install XAMPP in c:\xampp and launch XAMPP control panel, then run all services over there. All services except Apache module correctly run. I think main port for Apache conflicts with another services in Windows. For this reason I change Apache main port from 80 to 81, but this does not solve the problem.

Comment: The Apache module needs port 443 as well. This port this often blocked by Skype...

Comment: Have you looked into your Apache logs? What do they say? I believe XAMPP provides a direct link to your logs in one of its menus. Scroll to the end and see what log(s) match the time you try starting XAMPP.

Comment: Maybe a [dup of this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10749395/xampps-apache-not-working)?

Comment: thank you  for all dears for help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to change the apache configuration file(http.conf) to Listen to the new port(81)? Navigate to the file via the xampp control panel and search for 'Listen 80' and then change it to listen to 81.

Comment: mercy Myke for your answer